# Unwanted Toast Notifications

Tags: android, toast

Android 4.0 3. HTC Sense 3.6. I have some app installed on my SD card (1 of 195), that pops up a toast notification on boot/SD mount that says "Have a good day!" And lasts for nearly a minute. Does anyone know an easy way for me to figure out what app is causing that? Since toasts aren't a permission, an app like addon detector won't work.
Cheers!

Comment: belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you ever find what app it was? I have same deal, would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming specific question. Yet I believe I know how you could solve this.
If you have Eclipse installed with the DDMS ([I think it comes with the ADK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)), you can see all running apps, hence the app you are looking for.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The DDMS perspective in eclipse has a LogCat window by default (or should). If not look under Window - Show View - LogCat. If not look under Window - Show View - Other - Android - LogCat. With a device plugged into the usb you can get live updates in real time, so using a filter will help locate the guilty app.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `adb shell dumpsys` and search for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` under   `Registered Receivers:`.
Note down all the packages that have registered for this intent. Then do the same with `android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` (if the toast is coming when media is mounted). This should narrow down the package. If this is occuring when other intents are broadcasted then you should be able to narrow down further.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah think too that the easiest way (or maybe the only one) is to wait for the "event" and look it up in the device log in eclipse.